# Matlab: Plotting error Analysis

Tags: matlab, error-handling, plot, signal-processing

I have created a function which expresses the Ideal characteristics of Concentration Vs time and Real characteristics of Concentration VS time with Gaussian Noise.

Following are the curves of both ideal and real function

[image: ideal]
[image: real]

I would like to plot Error curve which expresses Difference between Ideal and real Values(With noise)

The characteristics must be expressed in( Noise - X axis Vs Error -Y axis) instead of concentration vs time

Following is the function that generates 2 curves expressed above

```
function [c_t,c_t_noise] =Noise_ConstrainedK2(t,a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,td,tmax,k1,k2,k3)



K_1   = (k1*k2)/(k2+k3);
K_2   = (k1*k3)/(k2+k3);
%DV_free= k1/(k2+k3);




c_t = zeros(size(t));

ind = (t > td) & (t < tmax);

  c_t(ind)= conv(((t(ind) - td) ./ (tmax - td) * (a1 + a2 + a3)),(K_1*exp(-(k2+k3)*t(ind)+K_2)),'same');



ind = (t >= tmax);

  c_t(ind)=conv((a1 * exp(-b1 * (t(ind) - tmax))+ a2 * exp(-b2 * (t(ind) - tmax))) + a3 * exp(-b3 * (t(ind) - tmax)),(K_1*exp(-(k2+k3)*t(ind)+K_2)),'same');

for mean=1:10
 for sigma=1:45

 c_t_noise = c_t+normrnd(mean,sigma,[1 500],length(c_t));

 end

end
dg = [0 0.5 0];
plot(t,c_t,'r');
hold on; 
plot(t,c_t_noise,'Color',dg);
hold off; 

axis([0 50 0 1900]);
xlabel('Time[mins]');
ylabel('concentration [Mbq]');
title('My signal');

end
```

Kindly suggest me a way in which i can possibly compute the difference between c_t and c_t_noise  and plot it

Comment: -1: What's wrong with `plot(t,(c_t-c_t_noise))`?

Comment: @Schorsch I would like to express the plot in (Noise(variable Sigma) VS error) not in Concentration Vs time

Comment: What is the difference between noise and error? Is `c_t_noise-c_t` equal to noise or error?